# Windows Service runs as console app but shuts down automatically as a service

Tags: c, windows, windows-services

So i have created a windows service which works in windows 10 as a service and on windows 7 as console application but when run in windows 7 as a service it stops automatically.

I have followed the tutorial here [DevX windows service steps](http://www.devx.com/cplus/Article/9857/0/page/2)

The service talks to my driver and provides the serialnumber for specific devices by executing cmd `wmic diskdrive get pnpdeviceid`.

Finally here is the main function and the serviceMain function

```
 VOID
 WINAPI ServiceMain(
     DWORD argc,
     LPTSTR *argv
 )
 /*
  Description:
    Service Entry Point of the service.
 */
 {
statusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(SERVICE_NAME,  ServiceCtrlHandler);

if (statusHandle == NULL)
    return;

// Tell the service controller we are starting
RtlZeroMemory(&serviceStatus, sizeof(serviceStatus));
serviceStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
serviceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
serviceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
serviceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
serviceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;

HRESULT result = ConnectToPort(&port);

serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
SetServiceStatus(statusHandle, &serviceStatus);

while (serviceStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING) {
    result = GetInformationAndSendSerialNumber(&port);
    if(SUCCEEDED(result)) Sleep(5000);
}

serviceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
serviceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
serviceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 3;
SetServiceStatus(statusHandle, &serviceStatus);
}

INT 
main(
INT argc,
PCHAR *argv
)
{
SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY serviceTableEntry[] = 
{
    { SERVICE_NAME, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain},
    {NULL, NULL}
};
StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(serviceTableEntry);
return 0;
}
```

`

This is how i install the service

`sc create Test binpath= C:\Test.exe
sc config Test start= auto`

Comment: @RbMm The service should remain on all the time and return serial number whenever a new USB is plugged in. When a new USB is plugged in to the computer the driver gets the vendor ID and the product ID and sends them to the service which executes the command and then returns the corresponding serial number, that is why i need the service to stay in loop and check for any input from the driver.

Comment: You need to add error checking, so that you can find where exactly the code is failing.  Also, if you put a modest Sleep() in main() before it calls StartServiceCtrlDispatcher you can attach a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it, it was a bunch of mistakes.

I had set the timer for FltSendMessage too long (100 seconds) on top of that I did not initialize the OVERLAPPED structure in FilterGetMessage which meant that the Service was put into wait state until any input from the driver.

Its all sorted out now. Thanks for all the help.

Edit:
Also I screwed up string matching which disconnected the service